# Return image from file system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There is successfully uploaded image in file system and I want to get access to it. So, I have written `GET`-method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string id) {
    var path = $@"d:\smth\upload\{id}.jpeg";
    return File(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

I'm totally sure that there is the file in required path with required name, but anytime a try to create `File(path, "image/jpeg")` I get `Could no find file` exception. Seems like i dont have access to folders outside `wwwroot`. Maybe I have missed something important from [working with static file article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)?

So, could anyone explain how to return image that stored in file system outside web-server folder via `GET`-method

Comment: Please use the correct tags next time, to get the appropriate answers! asp.net-mvc tag is for old MVC webstack! use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] for ASP.NET Core MVC!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While what @Shyju says is true and that the `File` helper method doesn't accept a physical file path, `PhysicalFile` helper method does (see [GitHub source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L711-L714)).

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string id) {
    var path = $@"d:\smth\upload\{id}.jpeg";
    return PhysicalFile(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `File` method does not have an overload which takes a physical location. There is one which takes a virtual path, for which your image should be under web app root.

But there is [another overload](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L627) which you can use for your usecase. This one take a byte array as the first argument of `File` method.  You can read the file from accessible physical directory (assuming your file exists) and convert it to a byte array and pass it to the File method.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string id)
{
   var path = $@"d:\smth\upload\{id}.jpeg";
   byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
   return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: btw. the referenced MSDN article is about ASP.NET MVC (you can see it on the System.Web.* namespace), not ASP.NET Core MVC, which is a complete rewrite of the webstack which do not has any dependency on System.Web.* (and hence no dependency on IIS)

Answer (score -2):

You can't, if you could, that would mean everybody in the outside world could make a GET/POST form and access your files outside the public folder. If somebody uploads a file to your webserver, it should reside in your tmp directory, which you should be able to access with asp.