# How does UWP establish communication with .NET Core Web Application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, uwp, httpclient

[image: This is my Project Diagram]

This is how my project like. For example, if one user type "Group1" in my UWP application, then it will send to my .NET Core Application and retrieve "Group1", there is a folder called "Group1", then UWP will download all the pictures inside "Group1" folder and display on the screen.

I want to know how to send such "Request" from my UWP to .NET Core Application and how it works.Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The post doesn't show much of your own effort, since its as simple as using HttpClient...

Comment: Now I can send post the image from UWP to Web Api already, so now the picture is stored in .NET core web application, I am currently not very sure about how to retrieve pictures from different folders from Web Api to my UWP

Comment: You lack the specifics. Though questions on how to return a file from ASP.NET Core have been answered around 100 times, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39311947/455493 or using the File method with a stream overload, depends on what exactly it is and where the file is located.In most cases its sufficient to return an json object or json array of objects with the urls (especially when file is located on cdn). Your question is just **too broad **